# Как называется удлинитель, снабжённый двумя или более розетками?

Tags: одним-словом, терминология

Как называется удлинитель, снабжённый двумя или более розетками?

[image]

Comment: Часто слышал название `крыса`: она же с хвостом :)

Comment: пример тройника советского [source](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&tbm=isch) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5glIv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5glIv.png)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Дополню:
На большей части территории России эту штуку называют "удлинитель".
При этом среди пожилого поколения, а так же в деревнях можно встретить название "переноска", которое можно отнести к местному диалекту.
Так же, пожилые люди часто называют их "тройник" независимо от того, сколько в них розеток.

Если в приборе имеется защита от перепадов напряжения - это "сетевой фильтр".
Однако, большое количество людей называет их "пилот", т.к. на момент появления сетевых фильтров в России самой распространенной фирмой, выпускающей их, была фирма "PILOT", а т.к. особенно старшее поколение не знало правильного названия - просто читали единственное слово, написанное на сетевом фильтре. Название прижилось, но сейчас используется чаще взрослыми людьми.

Подобное (Как с PILOT) так же было с копировальными аппарат фирмы Xerox - это настолько прижилось, что сейчас практически любой русскоговорящий человек назовет любой копировальный аппарат "ксерокс", независимо от фирмы-производителя.

Comment: *"пилот"* - это любой удлинитель на несколько розеток с общим выключателем. Независимо от того, является ли он сетевым фильтром!

Comment: тройник — это штука которая втыкается прямо в розетку (без провода). Пилотом кстати называют удлиннитель и без выключателя и с отдельными выключателями на все розетки.

Comment: @Alissa я лично слышал вариант "тройник" для удлинителя с 3мя розетками. Хотя сам обычно говорю "переноска".

Comment: Может быть зависит от местности? Я никогда не слышала слова "переноска". А тройником в моем окружении называют именно штуку без провода (даже если в ней две или четыре розетки)

Comment: @Alissa `Я никогда не слышала слова "переноска"` Переноской обычно называют очень большой удлинитель, метров, эдак, двадцать-тридцать. Возможно, Вы просто никогда таким не пользовались.

Comment: @Alissa совершенно верно, так оно и есть, такая вот [штука](https://07.img.avito.st/1280x960/1532384007.jpg) советских времен. Пилот, в советских терминах, это просто комбинация удлинителя с тройником.

Comment: @Matt Переноской так же называют, провод с лампой на конце.

Comment: А также _джип_. Я неоднократно слышал: _Тойота джип_

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&tbm=isch тройник советский

Comment: И любой русскоговорящий назовёт ...(нет такого слова) унитазом.

Answer (score 13):

Эта штука называется всего-навсего [*удлинитель*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?tbm=isch&q=electronics&oq=&gs_l=#tbm=isch&q=%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C). С несколькими розетками — это *удлинитель с тремя/пятью/шестью розетками*. Если внутри есть электронное устройство для подавления сетевых помех, тогда он называется [*сетевой фильтр*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80).

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: У нас "удлинитель" по умолчанию с одной розеткой. Будет непонимание, если розеток много. Регион: Сибирь.

Comment: @НадеждаТарашкевич - Автор вопроса [раз 5 переписывал](http://russian.stackexchange.com/posts/12671/revisions) его формулировку, изначально вопрос звучал так: «Как называется штука на фото?» Я свой ответ переделывать не хочу. Если вы думаете, что сотни фотографий по моей первой ссылке вызывают непонимание, то я тут ничего поделать не могу.

Comment: +100500. Удлинитель и есть. Раньше они были в основном с одной розеткой, теперь даже длииииные стали делать с несколькими.
Тройник - это вставляемое непосредственно в розетку устройство которое предоставляет возможность подключения трех и более устройств (классический, еще советский был обычно в виде усеченной пирамиды).


P.S. "переноской" с детства называлась лампочка с длинным проводом для использования в гараже, в сарае где нет света и т.д. и т.п. (Беларусь/север Украины)

Comment: P.P.S. Тем кто с лёту по фотографии типа вышеприведенной определяет наличие или отсутствие "электронного устройства подавления помех" для классификации среднестатистического произведенного в Китае сетевого удлинителя как "сетевой фильтр"  предлагаю открывать курсы гадалок - определенно будете иметь успех...

Answer (score 5):

У этого устройства две главные функции - во-первых, длинный провод, чтобы можно было подключить электроприборы на большем расстоянии. Во-вторых, количество розеток.

В качестве обладателя первого свойства, действительно, ничего кроме как `удлинитель` особо и не вспомнить. В качестве обладателя второго свойства, 
строго говоря есть официозное `электрический разветвитель питания`, но, так, разумеется, не говорят даже самые прожжённые канцеляристы.

А вот у разветвителя с тремя розетками есть вполне устоявшееся название - `тройник` - и если он с удлинённым проводом тоже. При этом слова, например,  `двойник` (в значении удлинитель с двумя розетками) по факту нет.

У профессионалов же употребляются прилагательные `двухгнездовой`, `трёхгнездовой` и так далее удлинители/разветвители. Так же можно встретить термин `групповая розетка`, например: "групповая розетка на 4 гнезда".

Answer (score 1):

Слово "пилот" применительно к обычному удлинителю-размножителю впервые услышал лишь в этом году.

При том, что я прекрасно помню времена, когда системы бесперебойного питания с сетевыми фильтрами Pilot продавались в магазинах. В конце 80х.

Comment: такое бывает - я тоже иногда с удивлением обнаруживаю, что все вокруг годами говорили какое-то слово - а я ни сном ни духом.

Comment: все же я думаю - это не особо распространненый вариант

Answer (score 1):

Прямо скажем, у нас нет единого устоявшегося слова для этой штуки. Я бы назвал это *пилот* или *удлинитель*. Но конкретно изображённую штуку назвать *пилотом* мне мешает отсутствие красного выключателя.

Выбор слова ещё, похоже, зависит от требуемой функции. Например, если мне нужно получить дополнительную розетку, я могу назвать это и «тройник» (понимая, что звучать будет глуповато). А если мне скорее нужно *удлинить*, я скажу, что мне нужен «удлинитель», имея в виду одно и то же устройство.

Answer (score -1):

Это называется "электрический разветвитель". По английский - electrical distributor.

Comment: Иван, добро пожаловать на Russian SE! Предложенный вами вариант уже был упомянут в других ответах. Практика показала, что ответы без дополнительной информации, добавляющей что-то новое к ответам, уже данным - часто минусуются.